# wget print a mistake why?

Tags: terminal, wget

I want to get an information of weather from weatherstack.com by wget.
But when I use wget on my Mac I faced a problem. Mistake:

[1] 7943
zsh: no matches found: http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=ACCESS_KEY
[1]  + exit 1     wget

Command: wget http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=ACCESS_KEY&query=London

Comment: Don't share your access keys online. Now everyone can impersonate you and use up your quota. Also, use HTTPS.

Comment: This is not a programming question and certainly not a java programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with wget in particular, but with how the shell looks at command lines. Here, it detects the "&" character in the URL and interprets this as the "run this in the background" operator.

To avoid this, you need to put the URL in quotes to "hide" the special characters from the shell. Try

```
wget "http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=YOUR_KEY&query=London"
```